# Could not translate expression 'value(DataClassesDataContext)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-4.0

i 'm working with LINQTOSQL Class for inserting,updating etc. opearation that was required for processing data manipulation task from web application to data base.

here my web application got problem for inserting and updating time error from linqtosql classes.

here are :

```
Server Error in '/EasyMail_New' Application.

Could not translate expression 'value(DataClassesDataContext).UpdateEmailField(2, "TotalFileSize", "0")' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression 'value(DataClassesDataContext).UpdateEmailField(2, "TotalFileSize", "0")' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

Source Error: 


Line 397:   public object UpdateEmailField([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Email_id", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> email_id, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="VarChar(25)")] string var_name, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="VarChar(100)")] string var_value)
Line 398:   {
Line 399:       return ((object)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), email_id, var_name, var_value).ReturnValue));
Line 400:   }
Line 401:   

Source File: e:\Shalin\WorkMaterial\EasyMail_New\App_Code\DataClasses.designer.cs    Line: 399 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression 'value(DataClassesDataContext).UpdateEmailField(2, "TotalFileSize", "0")' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.]
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Generator.Generate(SqlNode node, LocalBuilder locInstance) +637618
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Generator.GenerateBody(ILGenerator generator, SqlExpression expression) +276
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.CompileDynamicMethod(Generator gen, SqlExpression expression, Type elementType) +188
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Compile(SqlExpression expression, Type elementType) +367
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetReaderFactory(SqlNode node, Type elemType) +100
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +253
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters) +83
   DataClassesDataContext.UpdateEmailField(Nullable`1 email_id, String var_name, String var_value) in e:\Shalin\WorkMaterial\EasyMail_New\App_Code\DataClasses.designer.cs:399
   _Default.submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Shalin\WorkMaterial\EasyMail_New\Mail.aspx.cs:1309
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

i 'm just googled out and trying to resolve this problem. but no success. Is that any one they can solve my problem.

please help me......

```
    -------------------Update--------------------

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEmailField]
(
    @Email_id int,
    @var_name varchar(25),
    @var_value varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF @var_name = 'Title'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [Title] = CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'Body'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [Body] = CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'ToUser'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [ToUser] = CAST(@var_value AS TEXT) WHERE (Id=@Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'IsFileAttached'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [IsFileAttached]  = CAST(@var_value AS BIT) WHERE (Id = @Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'SentDateTime'
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master] SET [SentDateTime]  = CAST(@var_value AS DATETIME) WHERE (Id = @Email_id)
    ELSE IF @var_name = 'TotalFileSize' 
        UPDATE [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Email_master]  SET [TotalFileSize] = CAST (@var_value AS BIGINT) WHERE (Id=@Email_id)
END
```

Comment: Why do you expect the body of `UpdateEmailField` to work?

Comment: can u please clarify what u mean...

Comment: Is `UpdateEmailField` a generated method for a stored procedure?

Comment: dbo.UpdateEmailField in stored procedure and i add as method in LINQTOSQL class. so i can directly access this stored procedure from linqtosql class.